# Python: Pickle parser, or tools to make pickle less brittle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

### tl;dr

How to get a parsed version of the pickle's data (one specifying, in a "readable" manner, what is needed to make the desired unpickled object)

### motivation

How to use keep as much of the "no boilerplate" user-friendliness of [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), while being able to deal with it's limitations?

The user-friendliness of `pickle` is proven by the fact that most take for granted the fact that one can save (almost) any custom object in one place, and load it somewhere else, until...

- you don't have the necessary modules to create the unpickled objects
- you changed one of the classes of one of those objects
- you used a lambda (yes, I'm aware of [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/))

So `pickle` is powerful, but brittle in the sense that it will break easily. It favors correctness over (implicit) flexibility, and that's probably a good thing.

But when more (even explicit) flexibility is needed, where should we turn? What are the best practices and tools around this effort? If I could get a "parsed" version of the pickle data (see tl;dr above), I can use it, and `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` to stretch pickle further. But perhaps there's already standard tools to take care of these problems?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [Inspecting a pickle dump for dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64850705); the tool is `pickletools` and is part of the standard lib.